# Find the position inside this Yii 2 query

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I have this following Yii 2 query

```
$find = People::find()->where(['c_id' => $c_id])->orderBy('totals DESC, id DESC')->all();
```

So imagine this query was an array. Everything found by this query has an "id" attribute.

Since it's sorted by "totals", I essentially want to return the position in the array where I can find this specific id.

Currently, I'm using this code.

```
foreach ($find as $t) {
    $arr[] = $t->id;

    if ($t->id == $id) {
        break;
    }
}

$key = count($arr);

return $key;
```

However, this code is vany wayow on a 100k+ result query.

Is there anyway to speed this up?

Comment: i am trying to understand  what do you mean by **findning position in array where i can find this specific id** , do you mean that you are trying to find a specific `id` inside the result array and detect on which particular index that id was ?

Comment: do mark one of the answers as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the result as an array  (instead of object) as

```
$find = People::find()->where(['c_id' => $c_id])
        ->orderBy('totals DESC, id DESC')
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

then you could find your value using array_search()

```
$my_index =  array_search($id,$find);
```

but for 100k+  you should find using a direct select in db...instead tha looping on php or load all in php and scan with array_search()

Comment: How do I do the direct select in db?

Comment: You could use a sql command directly in Yii2 or an activeRecord findBuSql .. or a an ActiveQuery ... there several way  .. eventually update your question with the sql code  (or pseudo code)  you need

Comment: Your $my_index is showing always zero, I believe because $find is not just a 1-dimensional array so it can't find the key? I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: could be   this is another reason for avoid a loop or a search on an associative array

Answer (score 0):

To get array from query in YII, you can use `queryAll();`

```
$find = People::find()->where(['c_id' => $c_id])->orderBy('totals DESC, id DESC')->queryAll();
```

OR, another way to convert the object into an array is:

```
$find = json_decode(json_encode($find), true);  // to convert all data into array.
```

And once you get results in array, you can implement the actual code for your requirement as given below.

You can use `array_search()` function to get index of your value.

```
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue");
echo array_search("red",$a);
```

The array_search() function search an array for a value and returns the key.

Comment: However, $find is not an array, right? I believe what's causing the most stress on this function is the creation of the array itself. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can check if $find is an array or not. use `var_dump($find)`

Comment: @kevinkt, Have you checked this?

Comment: Yes the error is this: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Comment: Oh, it means your query is giving an collection of object.not an array.
check my updated answer to fix this.

Comment: However it's a 2-dimensional array. My key is found inside the 2nd dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand you correctly but I assume that you are trying to detect the `index` or `key` for your desired `id` inside an `array` returned from an `SQL` query that is sorted by some other column like `total`.

So let us fetch records from the database with your query with a little change [**`asArray()`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#$asArray-detail) like this

```
$find = People::find()
->where(['c_id' => $c_id])
->orderBy('totals DESC, id DESC')
->asArray()
->all();
```

in the result, let us assume the `People` table returns you an array with the following dataset ordered by columns `total` and `id` `DESC`.

```
[
    0 => [
        'id' => 2 ,
        'c_id'=>2,
        'name' => 'John' ,
        'age'=>18,
        'totals'=>100,
    ],
    1=>[
        'id'=>1,
        'c_id'=>55,
        'name'=>'Bob',
        'age'=>20,
        'totals'=>80,
    ],
    2=>[
        'id'=>3,
        'c_id'=>85,
        'name'=>'Peter',
        'age'=>15,
        'totals'=>75,
    ]
];
```

Now if you look into [**`\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html) you will find `ArrayHelper::getColumn()`.

Let us use this on the array we received from the query, I assume that you are searching `$id` inside the column `id` so we will first filter out the `id` column like below.

`$idsArray = ArrayHelper::getColumn($find, 'id');`

this will give us the ids in the following sequence which is in the same order as the initial result set.

`[2,1,3]`

then lets use the built-in `php` function `array_search()`

`$key=array_search($yourId,$idsArray);`

Hope this is what you are looking for.